# CSS - How to remove 2nd vertical scroll bar without changing anything else?

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I am trying to get rid of a distinctly unwanted second vertical scrollbar that has appeared on this page I am putting together, see http://abchealth.info/doc-mike-special/test3/.

My research here led me to try and remove the 'overflow' from my CSS, but this absolutely trashed my layout, so I am looking for a solution that removes the inner vertical scrollbar without changing anything else...

I'd much appreciate your help, thanks!

Here's my CSS:

```
/* Generated by KompoZer */


body {
background-image: url(http://abchealth.info/images/bg.png);
}


html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;

}


div#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

div#mastercontainer {
overflow:auto;  width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

div#header {
background-image: url(http://abchealth.info/images/header-bg.jpg);  background-repeat:   
repeat-x;
position: top; height: 96px;}


div#content {
}


div#innercontentmiddle {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 540px;
padding:10px;    padding-bottom:510px;}


div#footerclear {
}



div#footer {
position:relative;  margin-top: -510px; height: 510px; clear:both;
background-image: url(http://abchealth.info/images/footer-bg.jpg);  background-repeat:   
repeat-x;}


/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/
}
```

Comment: On your #mastercontainer, change "overflow:auto;" to "overflow:none;" and it should work.

Comment: Not to be overly critical, but your page could stand some cleanup. Your `main.css` is getting applied twice, and you have a stray stylesheet link between your `</head>` and `<body>` tags. You never know when things like this are going to screw something else up. (I'd scold you for too many `style` attributes too, but I suspect most of those were added by scripts.) Again, I only mention it because if you break standards, you can sometimes get weird behavior.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that did the trick! @eaj, I appreciate your comment - I am a blatant amateur and after I followed about 5 methods here until I finally got my footer to get sticky -  without much cleaning up in between - I know it must be real dirty under my hood - and your comment points me in the right direction, thanks. Especially that rogue stylesheet shall be hunted down now.

Comment: @eaj, would you be so kind and be more specific about the stylesheet issues to help me solve that? has be giving me strange long night already...what do I need to remove so main.css only gets applied once? And I find 2 other stylesheets mentioned between head and body tags, but are those not part of another script? (lightbox) Or did I miss another one? Thank you so much!

Comment: All of your style sheets should be included via `<link rel="stylesheet"...>` tags INSIDE the `<head> </head>` block. You have two of those that include `main.css`. It looks like you've managed to take care of the one that fell after the closing `</head>` tag and the opening `<body>`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

change this: `#mastercontainer {overflow:auto;}` to `#mastercontainer {overflow: visible;}`

What's happening is 'auto' uses a scroll bar if the content is too big for the frame. Aka that div or w/e needs enlarged to avoid the scroll. Visible will let it overflow like I think you want. Either visible or even hidden would work with this code-- css is all about playing around and experimenting.

***Most browsers offer a plug-in called 'FireBug' -> download it. It allows you to edit the css etc of webpages while viewing. Very useful for css styling errors. Highly recommended for issues such as this.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Is the difference in effect of overflow hidden/visible/none completely dependent on context/ rest of the CSS, or what should generally be the difference in effect? And I assume you're saying firebug lets me make these css changes for my view/ temporary testing only without "saving" it? Thank you, great tip for a beginner like me!

Comment: Yes, the effects of overflow hidden/visible/none completely depend on implementation. Firebug is an excellent tool for testing quick changes with css- saves a lot of time for tweaking the styling of a page. Then you can just copy and past over the changed css code to your file! Glad I could help. This is a nice link to explain the property more: http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_overflow.cfm

Answer (score 2):

This works

`#mastercontainer { overflow: hidden; }`

or the above solution works too.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow:auto` from `div#mastercontainer`.

Comment: Removing it completely for some reason ruins my layout, nut changing it to overflow:none, as @Kyle suggests above, worked for me, thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is due to html, body { overflow-x: hidden;} then try using html, body{height: 100%;} it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Setting overflow-y to'hidden' can in many cases remove the vertical scrollbar. As can setting it to 'visible' because that means that overflow is visible which means no need to scroll, so scrollbars are not visible.

Those setting however don't always work, because of what is said at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow :

> In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space set to nowrap.

The above link is a good resource for trying to understand how 'overflow' works in general, it's not as simple as you could hope.

For instance, another note, from there:

> Setting one axis to visible (the default) while setting the other to a different value results in visible behaving as auto.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using ***ion-icons and bootstrap***, the issue can be in ionic/structure.css.
I was using ion-icons on the website and in **ionic/structure.css** I found these two properties causing the issue and changing them solved the issue.

```
{
  overflow: hidden;
  overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}
```

**Changed to:**

```
{
  overflow: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior-y: scroll;
}
```